# matplotlib barplot no dibuja el eje x completo

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

Creo un barplot con matplotlib, el cual tiene dos grupos de datos, y se dibuja el eje x únicamente bajo los conjuntos de barras dibujadas, y no a lo largo de toda la figura.

Inicialmente se declara una figura con 6 subplots, y luego, dentro de un bucle for se van graficando "de dos en dos"

`fig_bac = plt.subplots(2, len(salinidades), sharey= True, figsize=(11, 9))
axes_bac = fig_bac[0].get_axes()`

Dentro del for

`ax_s1.bar(tickpos, mean_graf1_bac, width=width, yerr=std_graf1_bac, 
          color=colors_bac, edgecolor='black')
ax_s2.bar(tickpos, mean_graf2_bac, width=width, yerr=std_graf2_bac, 
          color=colors_bac, edgecolor='black')`

El graficado está dentro de un for, que toma los axes de un subplot generado antes y va graficando los barplots "de dos en dos".

La imagen resultante es [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo? Encuentro otras entradas del foro con problemas de las etiquetas pero nada con la línea del eje en sí.

Gracias

Comment: No entiendo muy bien qué pretendes. Por eje X te refieres al borde inferior del marco donde se ven los ticks 0, 20 y 40, no? ¿Cómo quieres que sigan los ticks a lo largo de toda la figura? Bajo mi punto de vista quedaría mal que después del 80 apareciera el 0 sin solución de continuidad. O si por eje X te refieres a la base de las columnas verdes, en ese caso, eso no es el eje X. Simplemente es la base de las columnas (que cuando la columna es muy baja coincide con su cima). Tampoco veo qué sentido tiene extenderlo hasta que toque al grupo siguiente.

Comment: En todo caso, si tus datos provienen de un dataframe pandas, te recomiendo echar un ojo a seaborn, que produce automáticamente gráficos de datos multidimensionales, agrupados bajo diferentes criterios que tú puedes especificar.

Comment: sí es cierto. No había notado que lo que pasa es que el eje X lo está situando a la altura de y=-5 (aproximadamente). En ese caso la pregunta es, ¿puedo forzar que el eje x lo ubique en y=0?

Comment: Cambia el rango del eje Y para que comience en cero, mediante `axis.set_ylim(bottom=0, top=None)`